# Is this solution of martingale problem correct?

Tags: stochastic-processes, solution-verification, martingales

I'm reading this problem

[image]

and its solution

[image]

I think there is a typo in the highlighted part. It should be

$$\begin{array}{l}
=\mathbb{E}\left[V_{n}^{2}\right]+\mathbb{E}\left[H_{n}^{2} \mathbb{E}\left[D_{n+1}^{2} |\mathcal{F}_{n}\right]\right] \\
=\mathbb{E}\left[V_{n}^{2}\right]+\sigma^{2} \mathbb{E}\left[H_{n}^{2}\right]
\end{array}$$

Even so, I suspect that this is not true because we are only given $\mathbb{E}\left[D_{n}^{2}\right]=\sigma^{2}$, not $\mathbb{E}\left[D_{n}^{2} | \mathcal{F}_{n}\right]=\sigma^{2}$.

Could you please confirm if my observation is correct or I miss something? Thank you so much!

Comment: @badatmath I don't get your point. Could you please be more specific?

Comment: @badatmath you explanation is too short to understand.

Comment: Ya I believe there is an error. What you should get is $\mathbb E V_n^2=\mathbb E H^2 \langle M \rangle_n\$

Comment: (this is just ito isometry for the discrete stochastic integral)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is @why's comment that answers my question. I post it here to remove this question from unanswered list. All credits are given to @why.

> Ya I believe there is an error. What you should get is $\mathbb E V_n^2=\mathbb E H^2 \langle M \rangle_n$